# Linux NASM: What is the value in ebx when you invoke sys_exit?

Tags: assembly, nasm

In a Linux environment, if I write some NASM code as follows:

```
mov eax, 1 ; system call 1 - sys_exit
mov ebx, 0
int 0x80
```

... what is the value in ebx?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's the exit code of the process - your snippet is more or less `exit(0)`

See [this link](http://www.lxhp.in-berlin.de/lhpsysc1.html#exit) for a (somewhat dated) list.

Answer (score 3):

> %ebx is the status code for the exit system call

This means that whatever is stored in **%ebx** will be returned to the Operating System. Therefore, after executing your application on a terminal, issuing this command:

```
echo $?
```

will print the return code of your app.

Pages 20,21,22 of [Programming from the Ground Up](http://download.savannah.gnu.org/releases/pgubook/ProgrammingGroundUp-1-0-booksize.pdf) explains this very well.

Comment: Go ahead and try it, set `%ebp` to 11 or some other random number and after running the app do the **echo** thing.

Comment: Can you expand the acronym "SO"? My mental macros keep replacing it with StackOverflow.com :P

Answer (score 1):

In general the Linux x86 system call interface uses eax to store the system call number and then the following registers for function arguments from to right

1. ebx
2. ecx
3. edx
4. esi
5. edi

There's a very nice system call table here that outlines most of the Linux system calls:

http://bluemaster.iu.hio.no/edu/dark/lin-asm/syscalls.html

Comment: That table doesn't list what the arguments are, only their type - which is why I passed over it in my google results :)

Comment: I used that table quite a bit myself when I was injecting system calls from a debugger. It's compact format makes it very usable. If you need high level details you can just use 'man'.

Answer (score 0):

`mov eax, 1 ;` is the sys_exit code

`mov ebx, 0 ;` the value of ebx could be either 0 or 1, 0 means normal exit, 1 means error.